# Looking for implementation of the trait core::cmp::PartialEq for int

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to use int in a generic class which require its generic type to implement the core::cmp::PartialEq trait. I know int is implementing it because I can do 4 != 5.
The problem is that the compiler doesn't recognise and fire the following error :

> error: unable to infer enough type information to locate the impl of the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq` for the type `<generic integer #2>`; type annotations required
>   src/binary_tree.rs:80   let tree = Node::new_node(box 10);
>
> src/binary_tree.rs:80:13: 80:27 note: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq` must be implemented because it is required by `Node<T>::new_node`

Can you help me to find the implementation of partialeq for int ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`10` is *not* an `int` literal. It is a generic integer literal—it may be `int`, `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `uint`, `u8`, `u16`, `u32` or `u64`. Which it will be is inferred.

In this case you have not given it anything to infer it with, and so it is unable to determine what type your number is, hence “type annotations required”. If you want it to be an `int`, write `10i`.